# How do you tell if two people on Facebook are friends with each other?

Tags: facebook, friends, friend-list

My friend is John Doe. He hides his friend list from me so only the mutual friends who don't hide their friend list will see it. There is another friend I may suspect is a friend of John Smith and his name is Rob Smith.

Rob Smith also hides his friend list from me. I also tried checking his profile but he has no pictures to show for. Normally if I click on one of his public pictures, it would show a `Tag Photo` button on the bottom. However, he has no photos. Since some people have privacy settings that limit their `Add Friend` button to Friends of Friends. However, the add button still shows up so that means he set his to Public.

I've also tried the `See Friendship` where I entered both names in a link but noticed there was nothing behind it saying `Friends since xxxx 20xx`. It also showed no interaction between them.

So is there any other way to find out if they are both friends?

Answer (score 1):

Ask them.

If they're really your friend, they will tell you the truth.

Comment: What if I don't want to ask them anyways? Is there a non-verbal way of telling that?

Comment: @puretppc then it's your loss. This is their privacy for friend lists they have control over it, if there was a way to bypass it, then that defeats their sense of privacy control.